# Beyond Compare automerge 3 files script

Tags: c#, shell, beyondcompare

I would like to make script to make change as in picture automatically.
I mean I have 1 origin file and 2 files that are updated, but have no conflicting updates. Just as in the picture. Always when I try to do that, the script does not do anything.
I use this:

```
"BCompare.exe" left.txt right.txt center.txt result.txt /automerge
```

I would like to make some code in C# before and after this action.
Is it even possible in BC use this in script? If not is there some option how to handle conflicts?

If you have any idea which tool I can use, that would be great.

[image: Screenshot Beyond Compare]

Comment: See Beyond Compare help : Command Line Reference in menu.  You can create a BAT file with a command line and you can also add a script file with additional commands.  You can run bat files from c# using the Process Class.  The bat and script files are text files and you can also create these in c#.

Comment: I know there are these options and I tried it, but never got the proposed merge...

Comment: Did you try the options first in a bat file from a cmd.exe window?  Make sure you use the options from your Beyond Compare help.  there are a number of different versions of Beyond Compare  and you need to use the proper options that works with your version.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare expects four file names as command-line arguments for an automerge.

```
bcompare.exe left.txt right.txt center.exe out.txt /automerge
```

The third file is the common ancestor of the left and right files. Also note if there is a conflict, Beyond Compare will not generate output from /automerge. To force output when there are conflicts, you'll also need to use the /force command line switch.

```
bcompare.exe left.txt right.txt center.exe out.txt /automerge /force
```

From the help file:
/force writes conflicts to the output with CVS-style markers if /automerge is present.

If you don't have a common ancestor file, you can still do a 2-way merge, but you'll have to explicitly define the merge output with a command-line switch.

```
bcompare.exe left.txt right.txt /mergeoutput=result.txt /automerge /force
```

Comment: If you try the /automerge /force it will not give you the output as in the picture. i tried that already..

Comment: If /automerge doesn't generate output when you provide 4 filenames as arguments, it indicates there are merge conflicts (changes on both sides) so the file can't be automerged. If you check the exit codes as listed in the Command Line Reference, exit code 14 indicates there are conflicts. Using /force generates output with CVS style markers when conflicts are detected so user can manually correct file.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is not some simple way to use the funcionality of BC in the picture. I needed what BC app proposed. But I guess it is not that easy. I am trying it now with google diffpatchmatch library... in C#